# QTP clicking on webbutton closed the dialog

Tags: qtp

I'm on a page that has a Pop-up. There is a list in this pop-up. I should firstly select an element in the list, then a link gets activated and I click on this link. Then another pop-up appears. Now, I have to click on a button in the new pop-up. The button captured by QTP is store just under the Page object.

The statement is simple:

```
Browser(Browser).Page(Page).WebButton("Button").Click
```

But my problem is, after clicking on this WebButton, the new pop-up disappears, and the value selected in the list of the main pop-up is reset to default (none selected). And in debug mode, there is no this problem...

I tried all solutions, 
"ReplayType" still makes the pop-up closed, 
"DeviceReplay", the "abs_x" and "abs_y" returned by GetROProperty are not the same to the values captured using Object Spy. So I cannot click on the right position.

Could someone enlighten me here how I can resolve this?

Thanks a lot

Allen

Comment: And I tried to add some additional properties as abs_x or abs_y to the button in the object repository, the object then cannot be highlighted...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write descriptive program to click on the button on that particular pop-up. Spy the button and write the script in qtp, dont store that object in the object repository.

for button, use html tag or name to identify the object

Answer (score 0):

using this recorded script, Browser(Browser).Page(Page).WebButton("Button").Click

1). after completion of recording, goto OR and find the Unique property, 
like while Recording time ,what properties QTP taken, based on that u can do it (mostly if u want to identify any webobject using QTP, its going **NAME / INDEX** property values)

2). best thing is need to write Descriptive programing, using Objectspy